# adjust the alignment of different legends

Tags: plotting, legending

I used `Show` to combine a `ListPlot` and `Plot`, and each plot has its own legend. The code is as follows:

```
    list1 = 
    {{0.1, 0.3}, {0.3, 0.42}, {0.5, 0.48}, {0.7, 0.57}, {0.9, 0.72}};
    list2 =
    {{0, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.25}, {0.4, 0.31}, {0.6, 0.34}, {0.8, 0.39}};
    curve1[x_] := 0.25 + 0.5 x; curve2[x_] := 0.2 + 0.25 x;
    p1 = ListPlot[{list1, list2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0.8}}, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Orange}}, Frame -> True, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[PointLegend[{"Experimental data 1", 
    "Experimental data 2"}], {0.8, 0.3}], ImageSize -> Large];
    p2 = Plot[{curve1[x], curve2[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0.8}}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Black}, Frame -> True, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"Theoretical line for data 1", 
    "Theoretical line for data 2"}], {0.8, 0.2}], ImageSize -> Large];
    Show[p1, p2]
```

[image: plot]

Now I want the four legends to have the same vertical spacing between each other, and the beginning letter "E" and "T" to be exactly aligned in vertical direction. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** A much easier way is to use single `LineLegend` with point and line elements:

```
mixedlegend = LineLegend[{White, White, Blue, Black}, 
{"Experimental data 1",  "Experimental data 2",
 "Theoretical line for data 1", "Theoretical line for data 2"}, 
  LegendMarkers -> {Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}], Graphics[{Orange, Disk[]}], None, None}]
```

[image]

```
Legended[Show[p1a, p2a], Placed[mixedlegend, {Scaled[.8], Scaled[.2]}]]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{curve1[x], curve2[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0.8}}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Black}, 
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large, Epilog -> p1a[[1]], 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[mixedlegend, {Scaled[.8], Scaled[.2]}]]
(* same picture *)
```

---

**Original post:**

You can play with `LegendMarkerSize` manually to align the texts:

```
p1a = ListPlot[{list1, list2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0.8}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]], 
     Directive[Orange, PointSize[Large]]}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large];

p2a = Plot[{curve1[x], curve2[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0.8}}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Black}, 
   Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large];

legend = Column[{PointLegend[{Red, Orange},
          {"Experimental data 1", "Experimental data 2"}, 
          LegendMarkers -> {"\[FilledCircle]", 10}, 
          LegendMarkerSize -> {32, 12}], 
         LineLegend[{Blue, Black}, {"Theoretical line for data 1", 
          "Theoretical line for data 2"}, LegendMarkerSize -> {30, 12}]}, 
         Spacings -> 0];

Legended[Show[p1a, p2a], Placed[legend, {Scaled[.8], Scaled[.2]}]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, using the listplot as `Epilog` in `Plot`:

```
Plot[{curve1[x], curve2[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0.8}}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Black}, 
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Large, Epilog -> p1a[[1]], 
 PlotLegends ->  Placed[legend, {Scaled[.8], Scaled[.2]}]]
```

gives the same picture.

**Note:** Using the observation in  @Virgil's answer, you could also use `p1[[1]]` and `p2[[1]]` in place of `p1a` and `p2a`, respectively. Similarly, `Epilog->p1a[[1]]` can be replaced with `Epilog->p1[[1,1]]`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the update is very useful. Just a follow-up question about the update way. Without changing everything else (like the vertical spacing), can I enlarge the circle marker and thicken the line marker in the LineLegend?

Comment: @user15908, something like `mixedlegend = 
 LineLegend[{White, White, Directive[Thick, Blue], 
   Directive[Thick, Dashed, Black]}, {"Experimental data 1", 
   "Experimental data 2", "Theoretical line for data 1", 
   "Theoretical line for data 2"}, 
  LegendMarkers -> {Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}], 
    Graphics[{Orange, Disk[]}], None, None}, 
  LegendMarkerSize -> Large]`?

Comment: `@kguler`   LegendMarkerSize and Directive are what I need, thanks once again!

Comment: @user15908, my pleasure. Glad it was useful for you.

Answer (score 3):

`LegendMarkerSize` is the key.

As an alternative to configuring the size manually, we can simply redraw a new combined legend with a single new legend using a single `LegendMarkerSize`. Although kguler's answer shows how to do this, *I would like to point out here that it is possible to do this only using the two plots* `p1` *and* `p2` *supplied originally*.

First note that a plot with a legend is a `Legended` object in Mathematica. It is also a tuple of two elements: the plot itself which is a `Graphics` object and a `Placed` legend.

```
Head@p1          (* -> Legended *)
Head@p1[[1]]     (* -> Graphics *)
Head@p1[[2]]     (* -> Placed *)
Head@p1[[2, 1]]  (* -> PointLegend *)
```

With a little trial and error, we can use this to break the two plots `p1` and `p2` up into components and use them to build a new legend we can use with the `Legended` function acting on a `Show`:

```
With[
 {
  plot1 = p1[[1]],
  plot2 = p2[[2]],
  legend1 = p1[[2, 1]],
  legend2 = p2[[2, 1]],
  place = p2[[2, 2]], (* position of new legend; good default *)
  lms = 15 (* legendmarkersize for new legend *)
 },
 Module[{points, lines, legends},
  points = MapThread[
    PointLegend[{#1}, {#2}, LegendMarkerSize -> lms] &, List@@legend1[[1 ;; 2]]];
  lines = MapThread[
    LineLegend[{#1}, {#2}, LegendMarkerSize -> lms] &, List@@legend2[[1 ;; 2]]];
  legends = points~Join~lines;
  Legended[Show[plot1, plot2], Placed[Column[legends], place]]
 ]
]
```

[image: legended]

In fact, this should be relatively easy to functionize (honestly, I'm not sure why Mathematica does't have something like this already - perhaps because the whole `PlotLegends`-type functionality is relatively new).

Answer (score 2):

`LegendMarkerSize` is the key as Virgil said. Besides that, the legend system is smart enough to combine legends if they are placed at the same position. So, instead of specifying one legend at `{0.8, 0.3}` and one at `{0.8, 0.2}`, put them both at `{0.8, 0.2}` and then they will be combined automatically reasonably.

```
p1 = ListPlot[{list1, list2}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0.8}}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Red}, {Orange}}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[PointLegend[{"Experimental data 1", "Experimental data 2"},
       LegendMarkerSize -> {32, 12}], {0.8, 0.2}], ImageSize -> Large];
p2 = Plot[{curve1[x], curve2[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0.8}}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Black}, 
   Frame -> True, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Placed[LineLegend[{"Theoretical line for data 1", 
       "Theoretical line for data 2"}, 
      LegendMarkerSize -> {32, 12}], {0.8, 0.2}], 
   ImageSize -> Large];
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]