# How to automatically align multiple legends in Show

Tags: plotting, legending

I am looking for a way to align two multiple legends while I can control the position of one of the legend myself.

Consider the following code.

```
Show[ Plot[{ x, x^2}, {x, 1, 2}
  , Frame -> True
  , PlotLegends -> Placed[ {"A", "B"}, Scaled[{0.7, 0.5}]]
 ], 
ListPlot[ Table[ {i, i}, {i, 0, 2, 0.1}]
  , Frame -> True
  , PlotLegends -> {"C"}
 ]
]
```

There are two plots with legends and one of the legends are placed manually via `Placed`. My goal is to make second legend aligned with the first one (possibly placed below) without manual controlling.

I found several related questions but they do not seem to work properly. For example, using the method introduced by ubpdqn of the following question [Legend in a Show](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54886/legend-in-a-show) , one can write the following code.

```
legended = {LineLegend[Range[2] // Map@ColorData[97] , {"Aa", "Bb"}], 
   PointLegend[{ColorData[97][1]}, {"C"}],
   } // Column
Legended[Show[ Plot[{ x, x^2}, {x, 1, 2}
   , Frame -> True
  ], 
   ListPlot[ Table[ {i, i}, {i, 0, 2, 0.1}]
   , Frame -> True
  ] 
] , Placed[legended, Scaled[{0.3, 0.6}]]]
```

However, the resulting plot was not quite satisfactory since the size of the legends are inconsistent. Could you suggest better methods for this goal?

Comment: related: [adjust the alignment of different legends](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80334/125)

Comment: @kguler Thanks for the link. It seems that this post is actually duplicated. As Chris Degnen's solution is also valid(and different) approach, I will leave it as it is at this moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with the old-style plot legends package.

```
Quiet@Needs["PlotLegends`"];

ShowLegend[Show[Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, 1, 2}, Frame -> True],
  ListPlot[Table[{i, i}, {i, 0, 2, 0.1}], Frame -> True]],
 {{{Graphics[{ColorData[97, 1], Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}]}],
    Style["Aa", 12, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]},
   {Graphics[{ColorData[97, 2], Thick, Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}]}],
    Style["Bb", 12, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]},
   {Graphics[{ColorData[97, 1], PointSize[0.25], Point[{0, 0}]}],
    Style["C", 12, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}}, LegendPosition -> {-0.4, 0},
  LegendSize -> {0.4, 0.4}, LegendShadow -> False, LegendTextSpace -> 1,
  LegendBorder -> None}]
```

[image]